# Python: Understanding how 'return' works within a class (Learn Python Hard Way, exercise 43)

Tags: python

I have been working through Zed Shaw's Learn Python The Hard Way (FYI -- new to Python and programming in general). I've been loving it, but have been baffled by [exercise 43](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html) for over a week.

The premise is to build a simple text input style game (like Zork), where you give instructions to a runner. Here is a simplified version of the code for this exercise: http://pastebin.com/9YJ2PYDh

I understand how the game is initiated with this code:

```
a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

What I can't seem to wrap my head around is how *subsequent* scenes are returned.

How does the value returned in the enter method of each class, i.e. return 'laser_weapon_armory' in CentralCorridor, get sent back to the Map class? Or is it being sent back to just the play method of the Engine class? I'm not seeing the connection of how the value passed in 'return' of a Scene class can restart the while loop in the play method of the Engine class.

I've reviewed the answers provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734732/understanding-classes-in-python-2-learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-43), but it still isn't making sense to me.

Thanks and apologies for butchering any terminology.

Comment: The magic happens within the While loop in Engine.play, where the next scene is determined by the result of current_scene.enter(), and then the value of next_scene is assigned to current_scene right before returning to the top of the loop again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `scenes` dict in the `Map` class a key part to understanding this.  When we look at the while loop in question we see

```
next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
```

which enters the current scene and gets its name.  The `next_scene_name` is set to the returned value you're talking about.  After getting the name of the next scene it does the lookup

```
current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
```

which goes into the `Map.next_scene` method.  Inside of that we have

```
val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
print "next_scene returns", val
return val
```

which does the lookup in the `scenes` dict, and gives you back an object of the next scene.  The process is then repeated.

Comment: Ah, this turned the lightbulb on: "The next_scene_name is set to the returned value you're talking about." When the while loop hits next_scene_name = current_scene.enter(), the loop essentially stops until something is returned from the enter method, correct?

Comment: @msarlo are you asking how function calls work? I can't gauge the extent of your programming skills from just the above question.

Comment: Yes, but specifically how they work inside a while-loop. In any case, I figured it out. Thanks!